# How to Stop running Spark Streaming application Gracefully?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How Do I stop Spark Streaming?
My Spark Streaming job is running continuously. I want to stop in a graceful manner.

I have seen the below option to shut down the streaming application.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown","true")
```

[Spark configuration: available properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties)

But, how do I update this parameter on a running application?

Comment: You cannot set sparkConf of sparkcontext after the creation of sparkContext.

Comment: What do you mean when you say graceful? Is anything wrong happening when your app stops?

Comment: I want to stop the application manully. there are two scenarios. i am clear about how to stop it when some error happend, i have it in the code. but if i want to stop manually, i am looking for a mechanism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop a spark streaming job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582730/how-do-i-stop-a-spark-streaming-job)

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at [this blogpost](http://why-not-learn-something.blogspot.dk/2016/05/apache-spark-streaming-how-to-do.html). It it the "nicest" way to gracefully terminate a streaming job I have come across.

> > How to pass Shutdown Signal :
> >
> > Now we know how to ensure graceful shutdown in spark streaming. But how can we pass the shutdown signal to spark streaming. One naive option is to use CTRL+C command at the screen terminal where we run driver program but obviously its not a good option.
> >     One solution , which i am using is , grep the driver process of spark streaming and send a SIGTERM signal . When driver gets this signal, it initiates the graceful shutdown of the application.
> >     We can write the command as below in some shell script  and run the script to pass shutdown signal :
> >
> > ps -ef | grep spark |  grep  | awk '{print $2}'   | xargs kill  -SIGTERM
> >
> > e.g. ps -ef | grep spark |  grep DataPipelineStreamDriver | awk '{print $2}'   | xargs kill  -SIGTERM

Comment: do i need to set         sparkConf.set(“spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown","true")  
 before i run the above command?

Comment: Yes, you need the setting as well :) But please read the full blogpost.

Comment: Got it.. When this is enables, how to gracefully shutdown with in my code if some exception occurs.

Comment: Blogpost says - We can just set this parameter, and then call methods ssc.start() and ssc.awaitTermination() . No need to call ssc.stop method. Otherwise application might hung during shutdown.

Comment: If i can't use stop method in code, how do i stop it gracefully incase of exception.

Comment: I tried it this way: ps -ef | grep spark |  grep driver-20161101205113-0016 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -SIGTERM
 and had the paramter true. When i run this command on linux terminal, i am receving. usage: kill [ -s signal | -p ] [ -a ] pid ...
       kill -l [ signal ]