# Killing spark streaming job running on yarn cluster mode through unix shell on error/interruption

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have shell script which initializing the spark streaming job in Yarn cluster mode.I have scheduled shell script through Autosys. Now when i kill autosys job i would like to kill this spark job running in cluster mode as well.  
I have tried using yarn application -kill in shell script on error return code but its not getting executed. 
but 
 I am able to kill this job from another shell window.  
yarn application -kill command works perfectly there and kill the application.

Is there any workaround to kill cluster mode job on interruption (automatically ) through same shell ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop a spark streaming job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582730/how-do-i-stop-a-spark-streaming-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In error return code logic -> run  yarn application -kill <*$appid*> as orphan process .